# Animating a ball in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a ball with these two equations:
x(t) = v0*cos(α)*t and 
y(t) = h + v0*sin(α)*t− 1/2 *g*t^2 , where t ∈ [0,t ﬁnal] is the time variable, h is the height, v0 is the initial speed, α is the angle made by v0 with the horizontal, g = 9.8 m/s^2. The floor is at y(x) = 0.

I need to draw a small animation of the ball moving on the plot. I now I should use for, plot, drawnow, but I don't know how to do it.

Can you tell me how to obain this animation?

Comment: For more a advanced version using numerical integration with event detection, see the [`ballode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html?refresh=true#f1-669698) demo. Type `edit ballode` in your command window. You'll need to adjust the the animation a bit to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here are some test variables to start with, including the acceleration due to gravity:

```
g = 9.8; %// m/s^2
v0 = 2; %// m/s
alpha = pi/6; %// Radians
h = 30; %// Start at 30 metres
t_final = 4.5; %// Seconds
t_vector = 0 : 0.01 : t_final;
```

`t_vector` in the last line of code creates a vector of points from the initial time of `t = 0` up until our ending time in steps of 0.01. With these defined, our job is to go through each of these points in our vector and plot our ball.  Next, let's create anonymous functions for each `x` and `y` to make our plotting easier:

```
x = @(t) v0*cos(alpha)*t;
y = @(t) h + v0*sin(alpha)*t - 0.5*g*t.^2;
```

What you can do next is use a `for` loop and go through each value of `t_vector` up until `t_final` and plot the individual point.  You should probably make the point big so we can actually see what the ball looks like:

```
close all;
figure; hold on;
for t = t_vector
    plot(x(t), y(t), 'b.', 'MarkerSize', 16);
    axis([0 t_final 0 h]);
    pause(0.01);
end
```

The above code will first close any figures we have open, spawn a new `figure` and use `hold on` so that we can call `plot` multiple times and append points to the graph without it erasing each time.  Then, for each point in time, we plot the location on the graph as a blue dot, then make the size of the dot 16.  We also make sure that the axis doesn't automatically adjust itself by enforcing that the `x` values are restricted between `t = 0` up to `t = t_final`.  We also restrict the `y` values from `y = 0` up to the initial starting height, which is 30 in my example.  At each point, we pause by 0.01 ms so you can see the drawing of the points.

As a bonus, this is what the figure looks like as an animated `gif`:

[image]

Comment: @3abcDEF3 my pleasure! This was fun to do. Good luck!

Comment: @chappjc Hahaha OMG. I used to play that game non stop back in the day. Such memories! Thanks for your upvote :) ALSO: http://www.classicdosgames.com/online/scorch15.html !!!